# Passenger 3 with RVM and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, passenger

I'm up to install Passenger 3 with Ruby 1.9.2.

I configured RVM with Ruby 1.9.2 - `ruby -v` returns 1.9.2 - so far so good.

Then I installed the passenger gem again to have it for RVM.

After this I run passenger-install-apache2-module.

But this setup is using ruby 1.8.7, even though I let RVM use 1.9.2 as default and are currently using 1.9.2 with RVM.

How to let the passenger-apache2-script use 1.9.2 headers and install it into the rvm dir?

Yours,

Joern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page might useful for you.

http://rvm.io/integration/passenger/

Answer (score 1):

Check with `which passenger-install-apache2-module` whether the right binary is being used. If that's okay, check the shebang line (the first line) of `passenger-install-apache2-module` is using the right ruby.